# Multilingual flask application

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, flask, multilingual

Is there a preferred way to make a Flask application multilingual? Ideally, the solution would enable to `@app.route` the same view to use different urls for each languages, like `@app.route(en='/staff/', fr='/equipe/)`. I'm pretty confident I could hack something like that together, but an existing library would sure save me some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe that [Flask-Babel](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Babel/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, It looks very promising.

Comment: Unfortunately, a Flask-Babel doesn't handle multi-language routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a decorator that decides which route to use.

```py
def lang_route(en, fr, *args, **kwargs):
    # Find out the user's language
    lang = "en"
    if lang == "en":
        return app.route(en, *args, **kwargs)
    if lang == "fr":
        return app.route(fr, *args, **kwargs)


@lang_route(en="/staff", fr="/equipe")
def staff():
    return "staff"
```